# Using an active bandpass on a very small signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, microphone, electret

I am trying to design a active bandpass filter for an electret microphone (the output will then be read through a microcontroller to control some LEDs)

[image: active bandpass filter schematic diagram]

(Image source - [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html))

I want to use the following design so that I can replace R3 with a potentiometer to change the gain for different volumes of music, without changing the properties of the bandpass. However, is there a possibility that having the electret microphone feed straight into the high pass filter could cause the signal to suffer, before it has been amplified? Op-amps aren't really my forte yet, so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

[image: screenshot of datasheet for electret microphone from RS Components]

(Image source - RS Components part number 780-0725 [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1582/0900766b81582bc2.pdf), linked from [this product page](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7800725/))

Comment: What's the impedance of the electret? Do you have any specifications on it?

Comment: 2.2k According to the datasheet https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/7800725/

Comment: Please take a screenshot of the relevant specs and put it in here. (Links die)

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: It seems like you're separating the HPF, gain and LPF stages more than they need to be. You can reduce the number of passives and achieve the same effect. What do you want your lower and upper cutoff frequency to be? Audio (20Hz-20kHz)? Or do you want to match your filter's response to that stated in the mic (50Hz-16kHz)?

Comment: Also, what's your op-amp?

Comment: Also - the condenser lists a standard operating voltage. Most condensers require this DC bias voltage to operate. Your circuit doesn't have that bias so it likely won't work.